# How to remove lines from xml with additional if condition

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

I have two xml files.
First is a **config.xml** file:

```html
      <values>
   <s1>yes</s1>
   <s2>no</s2>
   <s3>yes</s3>
   <s4>no</s4>
</values>
```

and second is **my_input.xml** file which I would like to trasform by xslt:

```html
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<aaa>  
  <bbb>  
      <code>Code</code>
      <name1>1111</name1>
      <name2>2222</name2>
      <documents xsi:nil="true"/>
      <xi:include href="s1.xml" xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude"/>
      <xi:include href="s2.xml" xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude"/>
      <xi:include href="s3.xml" xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude"/>
      <xi:include href="s4.xml" xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude"/>
  </bbb>
</aaa>
```

**Output.xml** file should look as below:

```html
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<aaa>  
  <bbb>  
      <code>Code</code>
      <name1>1111</name1>
      <name2>2222</name2>
      <documents xsi:nil="true"/>
      <xi:include href="s1.xml" xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude"/>
      <xi:include href="s3.xml" xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude"/>
  </bbb>
</aaa>
```

So line should be removed from **my_input.xml** file if 'no' string will be assing in **confing.xml** file.

Below you can find my code. But I can only remove separate lines, but I am not sure how to add additional **IF** condition... Do you have any idea?

```html
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet 
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
  version="1.0">

  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="no" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>   

  <xsl:template match="*[@href = 's2.xml']" />
  <xsl:template match="*[@href = 's4.xml']" />
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Br,
Sol

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
<xsl:template match="xi:include[document('config.xml')/values/*[. = 'no' and local-name() = substring-before(current()/@href, '.')]]"/>
```

Comment: Really thx for this hint! But I am not sure how to check if it works.... Due to when I open a Firefox, it transforming my_input.xml on the fly and I am not able to see xml source of the transformed file (CTRL+U returns source file before transformation by xslt). I am not able to use online debugger like: http://xsltransform.net/ due to on this page there is no ability to add second xml file - config.xml (only one xml file is required)... **Another words, is there any ability to check source of transformed xml file by xslt**?

Comment: @KilsoiSamuel, well, if you ask a question about using two XML input documents with XSLT it sounds a bit off if you later ask on how to test a proposed solution. Any XSLT processor you can run from the command line, any XSLT plugin for your favourite editor or IDE or any XML IDE will allow you to do that, so pick your tool, don't expect us to provide them in an answer on StackOverflow.

Comment: As for online tools, as long as they support XSLT 2 or later, if you declare e.g. `<xsl:param name="config-doc"><values>...</values></xsl:param>` globally inline and then use e.g. `<xsl:template match="xi:include[$config-doc/values/*[. = 'no' and local-name() = substring-before(current()/@href, '.')]]"/>`, you are basically dealing with two input documents, even if not loaded with the `document` function. So testing that code online by inlining the second document's data into a global parameter or variable is also possible.

Comment: Thank you Martin I checked your code in xsltproc and of course it works. Xslt is not my world :). I thing it is more complicated (xpath variations) even than REGEX :). Thanks for advice. We can close a post.

Comment: @KilsoiSamuel, to "close" your post you would accept the answer that solved your problem.